# Looping twice in Mapper code using Hadoop Streaming

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I want to combine multiple data sets before sending the output to a reducer python code. Here are my data sets:

```
 student.dat
 studentid:gender:age

 grades.dat
 studentid:subjectid:grade:semester:schoolyear

 subject.dat
 subjectid:name
```

I want to produce an output like this:

```
studentid gender name grade
```

In order to produce the output above, i thought of running 2 for loops so i can first save into a dict the subject data set then i will combine the student and grades data sets, then before printing the output, i will retrieve the subject name from the dict so i can put it together with the other values to produce the final structure that i need to send to my reducer.

here is the code:

```
mappper.py

#!/usr/bin/env python 
import sys

subjectDict = {}

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.split(":")

    if len(line) == 2:
    #subject
        subjectDict[line[0]] = line[1]

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.split("::")

    if len(line) == 3:
    #student
        studentid = line[0]
        gender = line[1]

    elif len(line) == 5:
    #grades
        studentid = line[0]         
        subjectid = line[1]
        grade = line[2]
        name = subjectDict.get(subjectid)

    print '%s|%s|%s|%s' % (studentid, gender, name, grade)
```

When I run it locally (using cat), I'm not getting any output. It looks like the only for loop that is being executed is the first one. I'm not very familiar yet with python hadoop streaming. What am I missing here? The only limitation i have here is, i need to write this in a single python mapper code.

How to join these data sets?

By the way, just for added info, this will be the output of the reducer

Reducer output might be (gender name average_grade):

```
F Mathematics 4.8

M Science 4.5
```

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is generally called a reduce side join in MapReduce. So your map needs to output `studentid` as the key and you join the fields together in the reduce.

Comment: @binary-nerd So you mean to say,in the mapper, i should join the student and grades data set and use studentid as the key. Then in the reduce thats where i will join the subject dataset? How will the reducer get the subject data set then?